# How to quickly change which display is my default display?

Tags: windows-8, display

I have 4 displays, and I frequently want to change which is my default display.

Is there any quick way to change which display is default?

Currently, I am opening up `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution` and changing it there.  But that's not quick.